# Non-standard toolbar in Notepad++ when using "Send To" menu

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, taskbar

After installation of Notepad++, I have copied its shortcut into my local *Send to...* folder (`C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`) to be able to quickly open any type of file. In addition, I have also right-clicked this shortcut and selected `Pin to Task Bar` option from menu.

Finally, I have reduced Notepad++'s toolbar to just a few buttons, using `Customize Toolbar` plugin.

When I click taskbar's icon (shortcut), everything is fine. Toolbar looks like, it is supposed to be and the `Customize Toolbar` plugin *is* loaded. However, when I use *Send to...* menu, Notepad++ opens up with all the buttons on the toolbar and plugin *is not loaded*.

What am I missing? I'm using exactly the same shortcut in both cases, only from two different locations (one is from *Start Menu*, second is from *Send to...* menu). If this is not a bug, but a feature, is there any workaround for this? How can I force my Notepad++ to always have exactly the same toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect running Notepad++ in both cases with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) like this:

[image]

Check the **Current Directory** field. That can give you a clue what's happening.

**Workaround:**

Instead of **Send To**, Shift-right-click your file and choose **Copy as Path** context menu item. In Notepad++, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (open file), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste copied path) and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you are done.